# Internal communications app/framework for alerting demographics of people within organization of IT related issues

Tags: open-source, communication

Need a secure, low-cost (preferably [HIPPA](http://www.onlinetech.com/resources/references/what-is-hipaa-compliance) compliant and opensource) app or framework that can be used to alert people (based on customizable categories) within an organization of IT related issues and other messages.

For example some days, may want to send a message to people in the org. who 'use dell computers *and* are male *and* are within a certain age range *and* are have not yet completed certain internal training requirements' and may later in the day want to send a message to people who 'use have used X equipment in the last Y days *and* are male', etc.

Would be ok with building an opensource project (from say github) that requires some programming to set up to custom specifications, rather than a fully packaged app (I've seen things like HIPPAGRAM, but it seems to be more of just a demo app for a larger commercial API).

I realize that this could loosely be achieved with Slack groups or email list groups, but was hoping for a more specifically designed way. Thanks.